# Tomcat- redirect to default action from multiple web module

Tags: tomcat, struts2, struts

I have 3 web modules(all used  struts2 framwork ) deployed (independently ) in the one tomcat.

Example

1. Login Module
2. Account Module
3. Information module

Each module have logout button. Only Login Module have login Page. When I click on logout button it has to redirect to Login page og Login Module.

How can I do it? Is there anyway in the server(tomcat configuration) to do it?

Comment: these three are separate web-app deployed independently or part of same web-app?

Comment: in that case i believe you can use Struts2 `Redirect` result

Answer (score 0):

I guess these modules are of a single web-app's. Assuming that, you can always redirect to any page using the struts configuration(i.e.)the struts.xml. 
In the "logout" action module, invalidate the session and return a string.

```
  public class Logout extends ActionSupport{
    public String execute(){
        //invalidate your session variable
        return SUCCESS;
    }
  }
```

Now add an action result in the struts.xml file as follows :

```
 <action name="logout" class="somePackage.LogoutAction">
    <result name="success" type="redirect">Login.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

Now link the logout button in every page to the action file someContext/Logout.action

The button on clicked will call the logout action which in turn will call the Login page.

Comment: unfortunately that will not work since modules are independently deployed so you have to create a whole new URL :)